# RabbitMQ API Queue-Size Call: Bad Response

Tags: curl, rabbitmq

When I make a remote call using `curl` to get a queue size on a RabbitMQ server using a command such as:

`curl -s -i -u guest:guest http://host:port/api/queues/%2f/queue_name`

I get back the text `AMQP`, and that's it.

When I run the curl command with the verbose flag on, I get, in addition to the `AMQP` text:

`* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* Increasing bytecount by 8 from hbuflen
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* nread <= 0, server closed connection, bailing
* Connection #0 to host rabbitmq-stage left intact
AMQP    * Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):`

Any idea as to why the response is not what is expected (i.e. a JSON string containing the queue size)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the wrong port:

`➜  sbin curl  -u guest:guest http://localhost:5672/api/queues/%2f/myqueue
AMQP    %`

try using `15672`  and not `5672`, in this way:

`curl  -u guest:guest http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2f/myqueue`